# Regular expression /[a-zA-Z0-9_-]/ return true when passing `!!!`

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following regular expression `/[a-zA-Z0-9_-]/` and I need to return false when the string contains only characters from `a` to `z` lower and uppercase, numbers, and `_` and `-`.

- What is wrong with my code?
- Could you please provide me a brief explanation and a sample of code on how to fix it?

```js
//var str = 'EKyirtVHsK0'; ok
var str = '!%!irtVHsK0'; // should return false
var result = /[a-zA-Z0-9_-]/.test(str);
alert(result);
```

Comment: You have to escape `-` inside character class

Comment: @hindmost: Only if used in a position where it may form a range. That is, not at the start/end of the character class and not immediately after a valid range.

Comment: You said that you should get `false` when the string contains only numbers, a-z, `_` and `-`. The string in your example contains other characters too, so it _should_ return `true` like it does. It shouldn't return `false`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your string contains symbols that are matched with your regex that finds *partial* matches. In fact, if you use `str.match(/[a-zA-Z0-9_-]/)`, you will see you matched `i`.

Add anchors and a quantifier:

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]*$/
 ^             ^^
```

Or, if 1+ chars are required in the input:

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+$/
               ^
```

Answer (score 6):

There is nothing wrong with your code. Only your expectations are a bit off.

The documentation of [`RegExp.test()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) mentions:

> Use `test()` whenever you want to know whether a pattern is found in a string (similar to the `String.prototype.search()` method [...])

The `test()` method doesn't verify if your entire string matches the regular expression but only if there is a substring of it that matches.

In its current form, your code checks if the string contains at least one character from the range (letters, digits, minus or dash).

If you need to check the matching against the entire string you should use [boundaries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#boundaries) (and probably a [quantifier](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#quantifiers)):

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+$/
```

- `^` matches the beginning of the string;
- `$` matches the end of the string;
- `+` means the previous expression matches once or more; the previous expression here is the `[...]` range.

This updated expression matches the strings that contain only letters, digits, dashes and minuses and are not empty;  use `*` instead of `+` to allow empty strings; `*` makes the previous expression match zero or more times.

---

**Update:**

A better way is to put `^` as the first character of the range and interpret the value returned by `test()` the other way around. `^` negates the meaning of the range block (`[...]`). `[^a-zA-Z0-9_-]` matches any character that is not a letter, a digit, dash or comma.

> I need to return `false` when the string contains only characters from `a` to `z` lower and uppercase, numbers, and `_` and `-`.

A string that matches the regexp `/[^a-zA-Z0-9_-]/` is valid for your needs (it contains at least one character that is not a letter, a digit, dash or comma).

```
var re = /[^a-zA-Z0-9_-]/
alert('Valid: ' + re.test('EKyirtVHsK0'));               // false
alert('Valid: ' + re.test('!%!irtVHsK0'));               // true
```

Answer (score 3):

You could check if a character *other* than the specified ones is found and return `true` if it does:

```js
console.log(isValid("!%!irtVHsK0"));
console.log(isValid("char09_-"));

function isValid(str) {
  return str.match(/[^a-zA-Z0-9_-]/) !== null;
}
```

This `[...]` matches specific characters.
This `[^...]` excludes specific characters.

In this case, `/[^a-zA-Z0-9_-]/` matches a character that **is not** `a-z`, `A-Z`, `0-9`, `_` or `-`.

The [`match()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_match.asp) method will return the first occurrence of the specified pattern or all of them, if the global flag is enabled. If nothing is found, it returns `null`.

```
str.match(/[^a-zA-Z0-9_-]/g); // "g" enables the global flag
```

Please note, the `^` hat symbol has different meaning when it's not inside square brackets like `[^...]`. If it's outside, it indicates the start of a string.

I would recommend visiting [this page](https://regexone.com/lesson/introduction_abcs) to learn regex, it's very easy. You could also use [this](https://regex101.com/) to test your regex.

Answer (score -1):

```js
var str = 'EKyirtVHsK0'; // ok
var str2 = '!%!irtVHsK0'; // should return false
var result = /^[a-z0-9_-]+$/i.test(str);
var result2 = /^[a-z0-9_-]+$/i.test(str2);
alert(result);
alert(result2);
```

As stated by Wiktor Stribizew, you are doing partial matches with your regular expression. in this particular case it means the string will be traversed character by character until it finds a match or it reaches the end of the string. With your string it will match at index 3 (the i), and return true. Using `^` at the beginning and `$` at the end of the expression, you force it to match the contents of the entire string exactly, since `^` matches the beginning of a string and `$` matches the end.

`/^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]$/` matches a string consisting of any single character from a to z, A to Z, 0 to 9, a hyphen or an underscore, so it would match '3', 'b', 'E', '-' or '_' but not 'ab' or 'er', because the `^` and `$` effectively restrict the string to just one character in this case.

To test for a string consisting of any amount of those characters in particular, you have to introduce an asterisk (if the string can be empty) or a plus sign (if it must contain at least one character). So `/^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+$/` returns true only if the string is comprised exclusively of the character ranges in the expression.

You can also do away with the `A-Z` portion using the `i` flag, which tells the expression to do case-insensitive matches, leaving you with `/^[a-z0-9_-]+$/i` as the final expression.